# Building a multi-dimensional array using nested for each loops?

Tags: php, arrays, google-bigquery

I'm trying to build an array of results from bigquery, and am having trouble creating an associative array. The desired result is an array containing associative arrays with all the results.

Here is what I have, and what it produces:

```
//get the headings
$headings = $response->getSchema()->getFields();
//make headings array
$headingArray = array();
//loop through this array and build another array of just the names
foreach ($headings as $key => $val) {
    //each column heading:
    $headingArray[] = $val->name;
}

$finalArray = array();


foreach ($response->getRows() as $row => $data){    
    $i = 0;

    foreach($data['modelData']['f'] as $k => $v){
        //echo $k;
        //print_r($v);
        $tempData = $result[$row][$response['modelData']['schema']['fields'][$k]['name']] = $v['v'];
        $finalArray[$i][$headingArray[$k]] = $tempData;
    }

    $i++;
}
```

produces only the first result (there should be 9):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [firstName] => Dillon
            [lastName] => Landman
            [address] => 9044 Smith Hall 
            [city] => Boulder
            [zip] => 80310
        )

)
```

If I just print_r the all the rows there are nine responses, so the final array should have nine keys, each containing an associative array with column headers => data from that [0] row.

Thanks for the help, I've been trying to find documentation and there is very little. Also this API exports a huge amount of other data which is why I need this code to only show column header and result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting `$i` on each iteration.

```
foreach ($response->getRows() as $row => $data){    
    $i = 0;
```

Put it outside the loop.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($response->getRows() as $row => $data){
```

Comment: Duh.. Thanks!!! it's always a missing bracket or something silly. I literally have spent two hours messing with this in frustration. I will try and upload the full working script since I couldn't find any working SELECT examples with the new api in PHP